# How to set system_time_zone for Mariadb 10.3 on Windows 10

Tags: timezone, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB in Window 10. My problem is that when I retrieve variable `system_time_zone`, it returns `unknown`.

My Question : How can I set that variable?
[MariaDB Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDN8m.png)

**MariaDB version:** 10.3
**OS:** Windows 10

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: is this helping you out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: @MaxMuster, it does not work for me. :(

Comment: what have you tried and what did not work ?

Comment: @MaxMuster,I tried to set `default-time-zone` in the configuration file - my.cnf, but `system_time_zone` is still `unknown`. Per this article, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time-zones/#system-time-zone, the `system_time_zone` is determined when server starts. So I suspect there are something wrong in my OS. Missing an environment variable?

Comment: Looks like you had luck, and someone from MariaDB took your stackoverflow entry and created a bug report. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22615 .It would make sense if you created bug report directly in JIRA, please do this next time . It's nothing you can do about the bug, and there is no workaround, unless you consider moving your server to another time zone, or Microsoft Windows somehow figures whether there is daylight saving or not in the place you live.

Comment: Thank you for your information, @VladislavVaintroub